# Why so many metadata files in Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I created a new project in Android studio and got many files generated, where as my actual code is found in just one folder - `src`.

Why the so complicated structure? Please explain the motivation of putting meta-files at the root of the project instead of some inner folder named gradle.

[image: So much important stuff (highlighted) that at the dev time, is useless to be aware of.]

Comment: gradle folder only use to store gradle-wrapper.jar and gradle-wrapper.properties which use to parser build.gradle for build app

Comment: You can found the Android project structure and why the build in this way here : http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#ApplicationModules

Comment: The developers of IntelliJ/Android Studio felt this was the best solution :)

Comment: Every one having their own view as well as every think we need to do something different than Others  :) .

Answer (score 4):

> Android build system consists of an Android plugin for Gradle. Gradle
>   is an advanced build toolkit that manages dependencies and allows you
>   to define custom build logic. Android Studio uses a Gradle wrapper to
>   fully integrate the Android plugin for Gradle.

Android Studio projects contain a top-level build file and a build file for each module. The build files are called `build.gradle`, and they are plain text files that use Groovy syntax to configure the build with the elements provided by the Android plugin for Gradle.

Gradle is an automated build toolkit that allows the way in which projects are built to be configured and managed through a set of build configuration files. This includes defining how a project is to be built, what dependencies need to be fulfilled for the project to build successfully and what the end result (or results) of the build process should be. The strength of Gradle lies in the flexibility that it provides to the developer.

For more info you may visit

1. **[Gradle Tutorial](http://rominirani.com/2014/08/19/gradle-tutorial-part-6-android-studio-gradle/)**
2. **[Android Application Modules](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/projects/index.html#ApplicationModules)**

Answer (score 3):

[image]

First of all if you don't want to see those metadata... you can change it(see Image)..

gradle is required to compile your project. for example: In gradle file we specify minsdk version,maxsdk version and dependencies etc

To Know more about gradle go to http://gradle.org/the-new-gradle-android-build-system/

Answer (score 1):

> Why the so complicated structure?

IMHO the structure you are referring to is pretty straightforward but your assumption that all those meta-files are related with gradle is wrong.

1. Meta-files related with your android application are located inside the "app" sub-folder. You have some gradle files there because those are for the purpose of building that specific module.

As pointed out before in a previous answer the best resource to understand  the file tree structure for this part is [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#ApplicationModules).

2. You also have some metadata generated by the IDE (.idea sub-folder):

> IntelliJ IDEA stores the configuration data for projects and their
>   components in plain text XML files making it easy to manage and share
>   project configuration data with others.

And .iml files:

> A module is a discrete unit of functionality which you can compile,
>   run, test and debug independently.
>
> Modules contain everything that is required for their specific tasks:
>   source code, build scripts, unit tests, deployment descriptors, and
>   documentation. However, modules exist and are functional only in the
>   context of a project.
>
> Configuration information for a module is stored in a .iml module
>   file. By default, such a file is located in the module's content root
>   folder.

More info about can be found [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/essentials.html).

> Please explain the motivation of putting meta-files at the root of the
>   project instead of some inner folder named gradle.

As mentioned before in some previous answers some metadata is related with the configuration of your project itself and some is module-specific. One example is the build.gradle files. The global file has this comment:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
```

About the motivation I only assume it was for simplicity and to keep the semantics of the project structure. Other possibility is that it was just by convention.