# How to structure AndroidManifest.xml with custom directory structure

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have a directory structure like this:

```
build.gradle
module/
  build.gradle
  pack/
    AndroidManifest.xml
    src/
      com/
        example/
          sub/
            main/
              index.java
            foo/
              index.java
            bar/
              index.java
```

I am not quite sure that is right in the first place (too many top-level folders it seems like). It seems like it should be more like this instead:

```
build.gradle
AndroidManifest.xml
com/
  example/
    sub/
      main/
        index.java
      foo/
        index.java
      bar/
        index.java
```

Ideally I would like to have it just be like this:

```
build.gradle
AndroidManifest.xml
src/
  main/
    index.java
  foo/
    index.java
  bar/
    index.java
```

Either way, the question is, how to write the `AndroidManifest.xml` so that it handles the `main/index.java` as the starting point. I have this currently:

```
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sub">
  <application android:label="myproject">
    <activity
        android:name=".main"
        android:label="myproject">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Wondering how I should change these three parts:

```
<application android:label="myproject">
  <activity
    android:name=".main"
    android:label="myproject">
```

I would prefer not to create the xml resource files like in the `res` folder to keep `strings.xml` for the name and such. I would just like to hardcode the name into `the AndroidManifest.xml` if possible.

Also note, the `main/index.java` file contains a class such as `MyActivity`.

Comment: I would assume that main.java is an Activity so something like `android:name=".main/index"`? Btw I don't think we should use the web like coding style in Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, **it is not possible**. It is default project structure and you can not modify the `AndroidManifest.xml` file to have your custom directory structure for your Android project.

```
<application android:label="myproject">
  <activity
    android:name=".main"
    android:label="myproject">
```

Here `android:label` value is string resource. You can either modify them in `res/values/strings.xml` which is `recommended` or you can hardcode them and update them here only.

Comment: @Pollard thanks for accepting my answer. Please upvote as well if you find it worthy.

Answer (score 0):

As You want to access the `index.java` `file` which is located in the `path`

```
src/
      com/
        example/
          sub/
            main/
              index.java
```

You need to change the `package` name like below:-

```
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sub.main">
  <application android:label="myproject">
    <activity
        android:name=".index"
        android:label="myproject">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Reference:-[Why so many metadata files in Android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34450442/why-so-many-metadata-files-in-android-studio)